# SSIS package container failures with VS_ISBROKEN

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I am currently using SQL Server 2014 and MYSQL.

My package contain's a number of containers, each container checks a MYSQL table to see if there are any new or updated records between itself and a SQL table of the same name and process's accordingly, either inserting or updating.

Half of the package runs fine then it fails on random containers saying VS_ISBROKEN.  There appears nothing to be wrong with the Metta Data as everything works fine when run individually.

I have rebuilt various failing containers, created a whole new SSIS package, created new Connections for the MYSQL and SQL tables but nothing seems to fix this issue.

If you run the container on it's own it works fine, if you go in to edit a container and check the mappings all is fine.  There is just no pattern other than exactly the same error.

I am running out of things to try now, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Such errors can be a sign of table definition (or metadata) changes on a MySQL side.

For instance:

1. Column null-ability or type was changed
2. Column added or removed

Indeed, when you open package to edit and check mappings they are to be refreshed so the issue is resolved, but only until a new change of table definition

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there have been no columns added or changed, in fact sometimes you can run the package through from the beginning and suddenly that container will succeed but the next one fail.  Could it have anything to do with the MYSQL database setup side of things?

Comment: That error is really about metadata change. Can you try also these few steps: 
1) set  Run64BitRuntime to false; 2) Set "Delay Validation" to TRUE on all dataflows where mysql in use. 3) Try to load them sequentially

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already set the delay validation on the mysql connections and they are already loading sensationally.  I tried setting the Run64 but any containers only doing something SQL based rather than MYSQL take forever to run, have swapped it back and now struggling to get containers that never failed previously to run at all? Any further help would be great!

Comment: Just updating this in case anyone can help, it now appears that if a container takes more time to process the tasks within it, the following container fails.  Each container, pulls a number of records from a MYSQL database and puts them in to SQL server while deciding if they are update or new records.  If this step takes some time, the MYSQL drops the connection, I cant see why it is doing this as I have many other Instances or mysql doing similar things but with no errors.  Is there a timeout somewhere on the mysql side that disconnects after so long?